# Java Pushing an element into a single stack of a 2d array of stacks

Tags: java, arrays, stack, push

I have a 2d array of stacks.

```
public Stack<Integer>[][] GameBoard = new Stack[3][3];

    //make square
    public Stack<Integer> Square = new Stack<>();

    public Stack<Integer>[][] FillBoard() {
        //initialize each square to have 0
        Square.push(0);
        //fill board with squares
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                GameBoard[i][j] = Square;
            }
        }
        GameBoard[1][1].push(1);
        return GameBoard;
    }
```

In this code, I give every stack in the 2d array a stack, `Square`, with the element of 0. When I then attempted to add an element to a certain stack (`GameBoard[1][2].push(1)`) it adds it to every stack in the array. so instead of `{{0,0,0},{0,1,0},(0,0,0}}` it returns `{{1,1,1},{1,1,1},{1,1,1}}`.
My only guess is that in the stack class, the list that stack uses is static?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are setting every stack in `Gameboard` to the same stack , `Square`. So every time you push an element into any of the stacks in `Gameboard`, you will also be pushing that same element into every other stack in `Gameboard`. In other words, because you set every element in `Gameboard` to the same stack in your `Fillboard()` function, every element in `Gameboard` will always be identical. Instead, use a new stack for every element, like so(with `GameBoard` renamed `gameboard`, per java naming conventions):

```java
    public Stack<Integer>[][] gameboard = new Stack[3][3];
    public Stack<Integer>[][] FillBoard() {
        //fill board with squares
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                Stack<Integer> square = new Stack<>();
                square.push(0);
                gameboard[i][j] = square;
            }
        }
        gameboard[1][1].push(1);
        return gameboard;
    }
```

Comment: please don't propagate violations of java naming conventions

Comment: right direction - still incomplete :)